# SQL Left Join in a many to many relationship situation

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to collect some average survey scores on employees by location over time. These people can transfer locations over time for various reasons. I have 2 tables.

`Survey_Scores`: this table houses individual survey scores. It contains 3 million rows.

Sample:

| Survey_Date | Employee_Number | Score (1-4) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2023 | 1 | 3 |
| 1/5/2023 | 2 | 4 |

`Employee_Info`: this table houses info about the employees. This info can change over time and this history is kept by having multiple lines for one person in this table. Their rows can be distinguished by the columns record start and record end dates. When the record end date is null, that is their most current information.

Sample showing 2 employees who traded locations on January 4th:

| Employee_Number | Location | Record_Start_Date | Record_End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SLC | 1/1/2023 | 1/3/2023 |
| 2 | TEX | 1/1/2023 | 1/3/2023 |
| 1 | TEX | 1/4/2023 | (null) |
| 2 | SLC | 1/4/2023 | (null) |

**PROBLEM**: I need to create a view that starts as the `Survey_Scores` table, but with an added column that denotes the location the employee belonged to as of the `Survey_Date`.

I tried joining the tables on the `employee_Number` columns, but got an error in snowflake due to the many to many relationship here. I understand why it isn't working, because it doesn't know which row to look at, so I'm wondering if there is some workaround where I can make it return the location of where that person was on the `survey_date`.

My initial thought beyond what i have already done is to somehow work in an if statement that says: if the `survey_date` is between `record_start_date` and `record_end_date`, then return location. But I'm not quite sure how to get going on implementing that.

Comment: try this:

`SELECT a.*, b.location FROM Survey_Scores AS a
LEFT JOIN Employee_Info AS b
ON a.Employee_Number = b.Employee_Number
WHERE a.Survey_Date BETWEEN b.Record_Start_Date AND b.Record_End_Date;`

Comment: This was pretty close, the answer i got from Lukasz Szozda worked and is essentially the same code but with null handling.

Comment: @LoganNielsen There is substantial difference when the condition is on `ON` clause vs. `WHERE` in context of LEFT OUTER join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried joining the tables on the employee_Number fields but got an error in snowflake due to the many to many relationship here

SQL allows to join on more than one field/predicate:

```
SELECT s.*, e.Location
FROM Survey_Scores AS s
LEFT JOIN Employee_Info AS e
  ON s.Employee_Number = e.Employee_Number
 AND s.Survey_Date BETWEEN e.Record_Start_Date 
                       AND COALESCE(e.Record_End_Date, '2999-12-31'::DATE);
```